# Can I pass information in the 'InteractionCreate' event ? If yes how?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

*(Possible duplicate)*
Hey,
I'm looking for advice here because I can't quite find the solution I want exactly. My bot have a command **VIEW** that allow the user to get information about a tournament, in the form of an embed + button, the button being a register button that trigger the **REGISTER** command. The problem is I need to pass the tournament's name on the arguments. I really have no idea if it is even possible to do since they are in different file, but I can't think of any other way to do it.
I'll put my code bellow. I use slappey's command handler. If you need any clarification, ask me.

#### The **VIEW** command

```js
module.exports = class ViewCommand extends BaseCommand {
  constructor() {
    super('view', 'tournamentManagement', []);
  }

  async run(client, message, args) {
    const { author, guild } = message;

    if ("All the condition are good") { 
      try {
        const tournament = await TournamentConfig.findOne({guildId: guild.id, name: args[0]});

        if (!tournament) {
          const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
          .setColor(colors.Ormes)
          .setTitle(`Cannot find tournament : ${args[0]}.`)
          .setDescription(`Please try again or contact my owner at ${meta.mail}.`);

          const link = new Discord.MessageButton()
          .setURL('https://google.com')
          .setStyle('url')
          .setLabel('Our Website');

          const row = new Discord.MessageActionRow()
         .addComponents(link);

          message.channel.send({embeds: [embed], components: [row]});
          return;
        }
      
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor(colors.Ormes)
        .setURL('https://google.com')
        .setAuthor(`By ${tournament.creator.name}`)
        .setTitle(tournament.name)
        .setDescription(tournament.description)
        .setThumbnail(tournament.iconURL)
        .addField('Type', tournament.participantsType, true)
        .addField('Status', tournament.status, true)
        .addField('Participants', `${tournament.participants.length} / ${tournament.maxParticipant}`)
        .addField('Progression',`${countMatchesDone(tournament.matches)} / ${tournament.matches.length} matches`, true)
        .setFooter(`Thank you for using Aura-discord. If you need help, you can contact my owner at ${meta.mail}`);

        let row = new Discord.MessageActionRow();

        if (author.id === tournament.creator.id) {
          const optionBTN = new Discord.MessageButton()
          .setCustomId('optionBTN')
          .setLabel('Manage Options')
          .setStyle('PRIMARY');

          const delBTN = new Discord.MessageButton()
          .setCustomId('delBTN')
          .setLabel('Delete')
          .setStyle('DANGER');

          row.addComponents(optionBTN, delBTN);
        }

        if (isRegistered(author, tournament)) {
          const unregisterBTN = new Discord.MessageButton()
          .setCustomId('unregisterBTN')
          .setLabel('Unregister')
          .setStyle('DANGER');

          row.addComponent(unregisterBTN);
        } else {
          const registerBTN = new Discord.MessageButton()
          .setCustomId('registerBTN')
          .setLabel('Register')
          .setStyle('PRIMARY');

          row.addComponents(registerBTN);
        }

        message.channel.send({embeds: [embed], components: [row]});

      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor(colors.Ormes)
        .setTitle('An error has occurred while processing')
        .setDescription(`Please try again or contact my owner at ${meta.mail}.`);

        const link = new Discord.MessageButton()
        .setURL('https://google.com')
        .setStyle('url')
        .setLabel('Our Website');

        const row = new Discord.MessageActionRow()
       .addComponents(link);

        message.channel.send({embeds: [embed], components: [row]});
      }
```

#### The 'InteractionCreate' event

```js
const BaseEvent = require('../utils/structures/BaseEvent');

module.exports = class InteractionCreate extends BaseEvent {
  constructor() {
    super('interactionCreate');
  }
  
  async run(client, interaction) {
    if (!interaction.isButton() && !interaction.isSelectMenu()) return;
    console.log(interaction);
    switch (button.id) {
      case 'registerBTN':
        const cmd = client.commands.get('register');
        await cmd.run(client, message, [tournament.name]); //MISSING VALUE :(
      break;
      //Same for all the other button
    }
  }
}
```

The constructor of the **register** command is the same as the **view** one : run(client, message, args) and args is an array that take 1 value, the name of the tournament.
(Like this : args = ["myTournament"]; )

I'm not sure if this is clear at all, but thank you for taking the time to read this and sorry for any spelling mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way of doing it. You don't have to use the 'interactionCreate' event. Instead, use collectors: https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#message-collectors